# Excel highligting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have been searching for the answer on my own, problem is that I cannot find one similar to my issue. I have 2 columns of data "C" and "D". I am trying to set it up so that if "C" is a greater number than "D" it will highlight the row. I currently have 73 rows used, 72 of which have the data that I want Excel to read and interact with. So C2- C73 and D2- D73 have the data. How would i specify the highlight rule to accommodate this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a new formatting rule using the formula `=INDIRECT("c"&ROW()) >INDIRECT("d"&ROW())`.  I just selected "bold and italic" for the format, but you can create whatever you want.

[image: formatting rule]

2) Then in "Manage Rules" you can select the range to apply the rule to.

[image: applied rule]

(Note: Screen shots are from 2013 since I don't have 2010, but I believe it should still apply.)

Comment: Assuming you want the whole row to highlight and you have a header row, select the whole spreadsheet starting from row two, follow @emragins' directions (good enough for an upvote, btw), but for a formula you can use "=OR($C2>$D2).